# Php dynamic variable name in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

[The of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocTDZ.png)

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $i = 1;
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName($item->product->name) // item name
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity($item->qty)
            ->setPrice($item->product->price); // unit price
      $i = $i + 1;
}
        // add item to list
        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array(
          $item_1,
          $item_2
        ));
```

i just want make this dynamic , my php skills are not very high as you can notice
Could Not find a way to make this work, 
can anyone help pls?

Comment: Which variable do you want to make "dynamic"? And why not use an array? Or append to the list in the loop right away?

Comment: append to the list in the loop right away sounds great but it just didnt work when i did it, i must made some mistakes

Comment: Instantiate the list before the loop, then use `->addItem($item_1)` within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of try to name your items like such, why not take full advantage of arrays:

```
$actualItems = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $actualItems[$i] = new Item();
  $actualItems[$i]->setName($item->product->name) // item name
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity($item->qty)
        ->setPrice($item->product->price); // unit price
  $i++;
}
// add item to list
$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->setItems($actualItems);
```

Comment: this returns 1 item while there are 2 in this case

Comment: This returns all the items in an array named `$actualItems` edit: just realized your counter was placed inside the loop, moved it outside.

Comment: great, thanks man  anyway i still get "Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment."  But ill figure it out , thank you